# Android get text from browser

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to get text from browser by using `uiautomator`

How can I do it?

I've parsed  structure of `chrome` and there is only `android.View.view`
I've tried to use `getText()` function, but it's not helped.
Any help appreciated.

Maybe somebody know how can I do it by calling some chrome instance... or with any other method.

Any solution, with info, how to save android browser page as html/text will be enough, or how to select whole page. (except touching/long pressing text).

Comment: One way of doing is dump the current activity properities to xml file and read that xml file.

Comment: @Fresher Please explain how can I do it...

Comment: use dumpWindowHierarchy() Method of UiDevice class to save current activity properities to file, the default location is "/data/local/tmp".Then read that file using file operations

Comment: @Fresher There is no data from page only hierarchy

Comment: Are you running your uiautomator tests while your device is connected to your PC or are you invoking your uiautomator tests directly from your device without being attached to a PC?

Comment: @JustinPapez I'm launching ui automator when my phone is plugged to my computer. But how it can affect on getting data ?

Comment: I had run into a similar problem to yours. Unfortunately, there is no easy workaround. Ultimately, I ended up creating a .java file that goes to the web, pulls the data it needs, writes it to a .txt file, and then pushes it to the phone. The uiautomator test script can then process the data in the .txt file. All of this is automatically run via a build.xml file. It's not exactly pretty, but it works and functions flawlessly. If you are interested I can show you code. Let me know, hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

[UiDevice.getLastTraversedText()](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#getLastTraversedText%28%29) is the only way I know to get **highlighted** text in webview. I am also looking for a better way to test webview on Android.

Comment: How can I highlight text by uiautomator?

Comment: I am using navigating keys: up, down, left, right. I have to use http test server, so that I can control the html content, and what navigating steps to get the expected content. It's also ugly..

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, [UiDevice.getLastTraversedText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111001/uiautomator-getlasttraversedtext) has never worked for me. Since Android 4.4 though, the elements are exposed as the android.view.View with its text or function as content descriptors. Does not work all the time, but it is a large improvement.

Answer (score -2):

use dumpWindowHierarchy() Method of UiDevice class to save current activity properities to file, the default location is "/data/local/tmp".Then read that file using file operations.

Second way of getting current activity properities :
1. Use "adb shell uiautomator dump /data/local/tmp/view.xml" to get screen properities.
2. Pull the file to computer machine using adb pull command and read that file.

Comment: I need to get data from WebView, not activity properties. @ dumpWindowHierarchy()@  returns only hierarchy not content of webView